# Data Calendar atualizando sozinha

Tags: java, data, calendar

Tenho um método na aplicação onde acrescento a data do serviço o tempo de garantia que o cliente tem.
Para executar o método eu retorno do banco de dados uma lista com todas as vendas/serviços realizados e quando executo o método eu tenho uma nova lista já com as datas corretas.

E como já tive um problema com o Calendar que atualiza as datas meio que sem sentido eu retorno outra lista do banco de dados com todas as vendas/serviços e relaciono ela com a minha lista com as datas de garantia.

Porém, quando retorno a minha lista com as vendas/serviços do banco de dados as datas são as mesmas da minha lista com as garantias.

Como isso é possível? É por causa da minha entidade que é a mesma? Porém, não deveria ocorrer algo do tipo pqe estou fazendo um select novo.

Meus métodos:

Minha Repository

```
public interface IVendaRepository extends JpaRepository<Venda, Long>{
    List<Venda> findAll();
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value="Select * from jcf_tbl_cad_vendas")
    List<Venda> listaVendas();
}

public List<Venda> EncontrarDatasVencimento(List<Venda> vendas){        
    List<Venda> lista = new ArrayList<>();  
    
    for(int i = 0; i<  vendas.size(); i++) {    
        Venda v = new Venda();
        v.setId(vendas.get(i).getId());
        v.setData(vendas.get(i).getData());
        v.setPrazo(vendas.get(i).getPrazo());
        v.setVencimento(ObterVencimento(vendas.get(i).getData(),vendas.get(i).getTempo(),vendas.get(i).getPrazo()));
        
        switch (vendas.get(i).getTempo()) {
        case 0:
            v.setDescPrazo("Dia(s)");                   
            break;
        case 1:
            v.setDescPrazo("Semana(s)");                    
            break;
        case 2:
            v.setDescPrazo("Mês(es)");                                      
            break;
        case 3:
            v.setDescPrazo("Ano(s)");                   
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }       
        
        lista.add(v);       
    }
    return lista;
}

public List<Venda> ListaVendas(List<Venda> vendas, List<Venda> datas, List<ItemVenda> carrinho){        
    List<Venda> lista = new ArrayList<>();          
    for(int i = 0; i<  vendas.size(); i++) {
        Venda v = new Venda();          
        if(vendas.get(i).getId() == datas.get(i).getId()) {
            v.setId(vendas.get(i).getId());
            v.setVeiculo(vendas.get(i).getVeiculo());
            v.setCliente(vendas.get(i).getCliente());
            v.setUsuario(vendas.get(i).getUsuario());           
            v.setServico(vendas.get(i).isServico());
            v.setData(vendas.get(i).getData());
            v.setOrcamento(vendas.get(i).isOrcamento());
            v.setSituacao(vendas.get(i).isSituacao());
            v.setPrazo(vendas.get(i).getPrazo());
            v.setDescPrazo(datas.get(i).getDescPrazo());
            v.setVencimento(datas.get(i).getVencimento());  
            v.setTotal(ObterValorTotalVenda(vendas.get(i).getId(),carrinho));
            lista.add(v);
        }       
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Onde obtenho as datas de vencimento da garantia do serviço:

```
public Calendar ObterVencimento(Calendar data,int tempo ,int prazo) {       
    switch (tempo) {
    case 0:         
         data.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,prazo);
        break;
    case 1:         
        data.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH,prazo);
        break;
    case 2:         
        data.add(Calendar.MONTH,prazo);
        break;
    case 3:         
         data.add(Calendar.YEAR,prazo);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }           
    return data;
}
```

Método Principal para retornar a lista que apresento ao usuário:

```
public List<Venda> findAll(){
    List<Venda> datas = EncontrarDatasVencimento(vendaRepository.listaVendas());
    List<Venda> vendas = vendaRepository.findAll();
     
    return ListaVendas(vendas,datas,itemVendaRepository.findAll());
}
```

No método acima eu executo dois métodos diferentes para retornar minhas vendas, o resultado é o mesmo.
Executei métodos diferentes pensando que o problema poderia ser que algo relacionado a utilizar a mesma consulta (ainda penso que pode ser).

Resultado para o usuário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Data correta que deveria aparecer na coluna Data Serviço:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei por qual motivo uma alteração está afetando um select que estou fazendo.
Alguém saberia me falar o motivo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No método `ObterVencimento` você chama o [método `add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,int)), que **modifica** o `Calendar`. Por exemplo, se você fizer isso:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // Calendar com a data atual
System.out.println(cal.getTime()); // mostra a data atual

ObterVencimento(cal, 2, 3);
System.out.println(cal.getTime()); // mostra a data 3 meses à frente
```

Veja que mesmo sem pegar o retorno do método, o `Calendar` foi modificado.

Para evitar isso, você poderia criar uma cópia do `Calendar` e retornar esta cópia modificada:

```
public Calendar ObterVencimento(Calendar cal, int tempo, int prazo) {
    // cria uma cópia
    Calendar data = (Calendar) cal.clone();

    // modifica a cópia
    switch (tempo) {
        case 0:
            data.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, prazo);
            break;
        case 1:
            data.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, prazo);
            break;
        case 2:
            data.add(Calendar.MONTH, prazo);
            break;
        case 3:
            data.add(Calendar.YEAR, prazo);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return data; // retorna a cópia modificada
}
```

Eu também sugiro mudar o nome para `obterVencimento` (com a primeira letra minúscula), para estar aderente com as [convenções de código do Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado a alteração adicionando o cal.clone() funcionou. Mas, sabe me falar pqe essa modificação do Calendar é tão profunda a ponto de afetar o valor de uma nova consulta no banco de dados?

Comment: @DSCM O `Calendar` em si não tem nada a ver com o  banco de dados. O que pode estar acontecendo é que essa data modificada estava sendo gravada no banco, por isso na próxima consulta trazia o novo valor. É o único jeito disso acontecer, pois o `Calendar` sozinho não consegue atualizar o banco

Comment: Sim, não digo que a minha data no banco foi modificada é o resultado da minha consulta que estava com a data modificada. Por esse motivo não estava entendendo nada eu estava fazendo uma nova consulta e minha data estava com o resultada da modificação que tinha feito na obtenção da minha data de vencimento.

Answer (score 0):

Em *`java`* não temos passagem por referência, somente cópia, porém, a cópia aponta para as mesmas referências.

Portanto, quando você faz:  `data.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, prazo);` está alterando a variável original.

A sugestão do colega: *@hkotsubo* do clone, funciona, porque a classe [***Calendar***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) implementa a interface [***Cloneable***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) sendo assim, um novo objeto é criado com os mesmos atributos(uma cópia totalmente)

A alteração no banco de dados, ocorre porque você buscou do banco(o objeto está no estado ***Managed***) e quando você realiza uma alteração no objeto, os dados são persistidos no banco de dados automaticamente.